# registry launch condition for ie version?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

i am using vs2005 deployment project to build setup for my application. my application runs well in ie versions 6,7,8 but not supports ie version more than 8. i have created a registry launch condition for that but it even not allowing me to install in ie 8 machine also

here is the details of registry launch condition

Search for registry launch condition properties:

```
Progperty = IEVER
RegKey = SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector
Root= vsdrrHKLM
value = IE
```

launch condition properties: - i have tried those diffent kinds of conditions

1. Condition: `IEVER <= "8.0.0.0"`
2. Condition: `IEVER <= "#8.0"`
3. Condition: `IEVER <= "#8.0.0.0"`
4. Condition: `IEVER <= 8`

can anybody help me to overcome the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last we found solution, here it is

```
registry launch condition properties:

Progperty = IEVER
RegKey = SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
Root= vsdrrHKLM
value = Version

Condition: IEVER < "9.0.0.0"
```